# Am I running too many subqueries in my SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns

I have the following tables:

```
users:
    user_id
    user_name

message:
    message_id
    thread_id
    to_id
    from_id
    title
    message_text
    message_date        
    status
```

The desired result of the query I run is to list the `title` of the most recent message from the most recent threads a long with the `thread_id` and `username` and to sort the result by `date` in descending order. I'm only going to be listing about 10 to 20 results at a time most likely.

The SQL query I came up with seems to be doing this so far, but I feel like I have over complicated it and that there may be a more optimal way to write my query.

```
    SELECT personal_messages.message_id, 
           personal_messages.thread_id, 
           personal_messages.body, 
           users.username
    FROM users, personal_messages
    WHERE message_id IN 
        (SELECT MAX(message_id) from personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id)
    AND users.id IN 
        (SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id = personal_messages.from_id)
    ORDER BY personal_messages.message_date DESC
```

Also, if anyone knows a way to get the `count` of all the messages with the same `thread_id`, that would be awesome!

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to remove the "design-patterns" tag.  If not, clarify what design pattern(s) you believe are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the subselects could be unnecessary

```
SELECT personal_messages.message_id, personal_messages.thread_id, personal_messages.body, users.username
FROM users INNER JOIN personal_messages ON (users.id = personal_messages.from_id)
WHERE message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id) from personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id)
ORDER BY personal_messages.message_date DESC
```

Edit: Also, if anyone knows a way to get the count of all the messages with the same thread_id, that would be awesome!

```
SELECT MAX(message_id), COUNT(message_id) FROM personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id
```

Comment: This partially works. The top part works great, however the second part with the `COUNT` throws the following error: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.message_id, personal_messages.thread_id
       , personal_messages.body, users.username
FROM users u
JOIN personal_messages tbl on tbl. from_id = u.UsersId
WHERE tbl.message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id) from personal_messages 
GROUP BY thread_id)
ORDER BY personal_messages.message_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are too many subqueries in your query but it can be written more optimally. I think the below query should work equally well:

```
SELECT `PM`.`message_id`, `PM`.`thread_id`, `PM`.`body`, `U`.`username`
FROM `users` `U`
INNER JOIN `personal_messages` `PM` ON `PM`.`from_id` = `U`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `PM`.`message_date` DESC;
```

The issues that I've found with your query are:

1. The first sub-query - `SELECT MAX(message_id) from personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id` - will always return a single resultset, so using an IN doesn't make sense
2. For the second sub-query - `SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id = personal_messages.from_id` - you may use an INNER JOIN instead, like in my example

Hope the above helps.

Also, I'm not sure on what info are you actually trying to retrieve. But the above query should give you the details for the most recent message, along with its thread id and username.

**EDITED** query to select one latest message per thread:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT `PM`.`message_id`, `PM`.`thread_id`, `PM`.`body`, `U`.`username`
    FROM `users` `U`
    INNER JOIN `personal_messages` `PM` ON `PM`.`from_id` = `U`.`user_id`
    ORDER BY `PM`.`message_date` DESC;
) `TT`
GROUP BY `TT`.`thread_id`;
```

Comment: I don't see how your query will work, how is it select just one message from each thread?

Comment: @bigmike7801: please see my edited query above, it will give you the latest message per thread

Comment: Nope sorry, doesn't give the desired result of most recent message from a particular thread. This query runs great though `SELECT personal_messages.message_id, personal_messages.thread_id, personal_messages.body, users.username
        FROM users 
        INNER JOIN personal_messages ON (users.id = personal_messages.from_id)
        WHERE message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id)
        ORDER BY personal_messages.message_date DESC`

Comment: @bigmike7801: I'm sorry but I think I didn't understand your question then because, from the logic of my query, it seemed to return latest message per thread. Instead, from the query you had mentioned in your last comment, it seems to me (and as I've as well said in point1 in my response) that it might always return one record because the sub-query `(SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM personal_messages GROUP BY thread_id)` will always give the max message_id. So I'm not sure how this query will give latest message per thread; I think it will always give latest message and it's thread. Pls advice.

Answer (score 0):

What you have already is pretty good.  If you want to do it all with one query, you could  get the `COUNT(message_id) GROUP BY thread_id` as part of the same subselect that gets the `MAX(message_id) GROUP BY thread_id`:

```
SELECT personal_messages.message_id,
       personal_messages.thread_id,
       personal_messages.body,
       users.username,
       thread.countmessages
FROM personal_messages
JOIN users ON users.id=personal_messages.from_id
JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(message_id) countmessages, 
             MAX(message_id) maxmessage_id
         FROM personal_messages
         GROUP BY thread_id) AS thread 
     ON thread.maxmessage_id=personal_messages.message_id
ORDER BY personal_messages.message_date DESC
```